# How to use bind_result function with SELECT * query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am looking for a way to get complete row from mysqli prepared statement without knowing the number of columns

This is what I have tested successfully

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM users where user_id = ?")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', '32');        
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($user_id);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
      printf ("%s \n", $user_id);
  }
  $stmt->close();
}
```

This worked fine but what about if I want all columns and my query will be *

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_id = ?")) {
  $stmt->bind_param('s', '32');        
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();
}
```

How to use mysqli prepared statement for `SELECT *`?

Comment: Use PDO instead of mysqli. With PDO [you'll never have any hassle like this](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison).

Comment: is there any way in mysqli

Comment: Yes, as you may have learned already, if clicked the link I posted

Comment: will you please quote any working example

Comment: i just want to get rid of `bind_result()` because number of columns is unknown

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching an unknown number of columns from the result set then you can't use `bind_result()`. This function is useful for a single column or if you have a small fixed number of columns.

To get the result from `SELECT *` use `get_result()` which will return a `mysqli_result` object which you can iterate over or fetch a single row.

```
$user_id = 32;
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);        
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
foreach($result as $row) {
    printf ("%s \n", $row['username']);
}
```

<sub>This function is not available on some very old PHP releases or ones that are compiled against libmysql client</sub>